# Converting from RGB to depth

Tags: ros, navigation, mapping, kinect, depth

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hello,

i know  that given a (u,v,depth) in the depth image it is easy to retreive the corresponding rgb pixel by unporjecting the depth pixel and projecting to RGB image using the [R T]
now my question is, is it possible to do the inverse ? ( having an rgb pixel, retreive the corresponding depth pixel?) and if yes, how ?
thx

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9231/converting-from-rgb-to-depth/) by [caspersky](https://answers.ros.org/users/207/caspersky/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2011-02-28

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

openni_camera already provides what you are looking for by default in its current version!

If you have a look at the rgb and depth image you will find that the depth image is already transformed and projected to camera coordinates of the rgb camera:
[image: image description]

Note that you can turn this off by changing the setting for depth_registration after running:

```
rosrun dynamic_reconfigure reconfigure_gui
```

Make sure to have a look at the [wiki page](http://www.ros.org/wiki/openni_camera) as well.

---

Originally posted by [sebsch](https://answers.ros.org/users/23/sebsch/) with karma: 790 on 2011-03-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 9